# Add new button to PageDown markdown editor

Tags: javascript, markdown, pagedown

How do I add a new button to the PageDown markdown editor located at http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/?  Ideally, the button would create a dialog like that used to add a link or image, but any type of examples would be very helpful.

Comment: [Here is a fork of pagedown](https://github.com/JohnnyZhao/pagedown-bootstrap-i18n), and we've just add a emotion button, check it out~