# Pagedown Bootstrap - Missing Button Icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagedown

Have had a search on here and Google and am unable to find anyone else with this issue.

The screenshot below shows the issue I am having. The fourth icon from the right is missing, and is not click able either. I believe the missing icon is for the 'heading' icon.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVuzH.png)

I have not modified any of the files from pagedown bootstrap.

all the other icons work fine which makes me think this is not an issue with a missing .css file or something, perhaps there has been a name change for one of the icons since update?

If you need any more information please comment, I am unsure of what other info would be appropriate.

**more info**

I have realised part of the problem, I am not using LESS (which creates the icons from a .png)

So that explains why the icon isn't showing.

What is strange is that all the other icons *do* show, and I believe they are from the font-awesome icon set.

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 3.0 - thanks

Comment: have you changed the path of image?

Comment: Nope, haven't changed anything. I believe that it is drawn out using glyphicons or font-awesome as opposed to using an image for the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the pagedown-bootstrap-rails gem, I was having the exact same problem. I looked through the code on github and it seems like that very same icon (for the heading) is the only glyphicon (as opposed to font-awesome icon) used. As a workaround I forked the repo, made changes, and am using my fork at the moment in my project, until my changes get merged. Try using it and seeing if it fixes your problem, maybe it helps! Here's the link:
https://github.com/alicetragedy/pagedown-bootstrap-rails

Comment: Alternatively, this could bring you on the right path, too. Sorry for my answer above, I stupidly assumed you were using rails. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483484/add-new-button-to-pagedown-markdown-editor